# single table four columns into 8 columns

Tags: sql

I have below single table with 5 rows and 4 columns, I wanted to have the result set of 8 columns, tried a inner join on same table but did not get the expected result, is there any way to get selected records from the below query result set?

```
Declare @CustomerData Table (CustomerNum int,
    VehicleName Char(20),
    Vehiclepurchaseyear char(4),
    Vehicleprice char(10))
INSERT INTO @CustomerData(CustomerNum,VehicleName,Vehiclepurchaseyear,Vehicleprice)
VALUES (1000,'Toyoto Camry','2012',' 14500'),
    (1000,'Nissan Ultima','2014','12000'),
    (1500,'Honda Accord','2012','15000'),
    (1500,'Honda Civic','2012','13000'),
    (1800,'Toyoto RAV4','2012','16500')
SELECT X.customerNum as CustomerNum
    ,X.VehicleName as Vehiclename1   
    ,X.Vehiclepurchaseyear as  vehiclepurchaseyear1 
    ,X.Vehicleprice        as  vehicleprice1 
    ,Y.VehicleName as Vehiclename2   
    ,Y.Vehiclepurchaseyear as  vehiclepurchaseyear2
    ,Y.Vehicleprice        as  vehicleprice2
FROM 
    (SELECT CustomerNum,
        VehicleName,
        Vehiclepurchaseyear,
        Vehicleprice
     FROM @Customerdata ) X
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT CustomerNum,
        VehicleName,
        Vehiclepurchaseyear,
        Vehicleprice
     FROM @CustomerData ) Y
on X.CustomerNum = Y.customernum
```

result not expected :

```
1000    Toyoto Camry            2012     14500      Toyoto Camry            2012     14500    
1000    Toyoto Camry            2012     14500      Nissan Ultima           2014    12000     
1000    Nissan Ultima           2014    12000       Toyoto Camry            2012     14500    
1000    Nissan Ultima           2014    12000       Nissan Ultima           2014    12000     
1500    Honda Accord            2012    15000       Honda Accord            2012    15000     
1500    Honda Accord            2012    15000       Honda Civic             2012    13000     
1500    Honda Civic             2012    13000       Honda Accord            2012    15000     
1500    Honda Civic             2012    13000       Honda Civic             2012    13000     
1800    Toyoto RAV4             2012    16500       Toyoto RAV4             2012    16500
```

expected result  :

```
1000    Toyoto Camry            2012     14500      Nissan Ultima           2014    12000
1500    Honda Civic             2012     13000      Honda Accord            2012    15000 
1800    Toyoto RAV4             2012
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Format properly.  It is very hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just guessing, but this seems to be what you're wanting

```
SELECT  cd.CustomerNum,
       MAX( CASE WHEN Rn = 1 THEN cd.VehicleName END) AS VehicleName1,
       MAX( CASE WHEN Rn = 1 THEN cd.VehiclePurchaseYear  END) AS VehiclePurchaseYear1,
       MAX( CASE WHEN Rn = 1 THEN cd.VehiclePrice END) AS VehiclePrice1,
       MAX( CASE WHEN Rn = 2 THEN cd.VehicleName END) AS VehicleName2,
       MAX( CASE WHEN Rn = 2 THEN cd.VehiclePurchaseYear END) AS VehiclePurchaseYear2,
       MAX( CASE WHEN Rn = 2 THEN cd.VehiclePrice END) AS VehiclePrice2
FROM   ( SELECT *, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerNum ORDER BY VehiclePurchaseYear) Rn
        FROM    @Customerdata) cd
GROUP BY cd.CustomerNum
```

this will sort each customer's purchase by year and give you the first result as Rn 1 and the second purchase as Rn 2.

it's not going to be reliable if 2 cars were purchased in the same year, so you might want to include a DateTime stamp to order it by.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the desired result on this small table, but you should make each line have a unique id and instead of saying x.vehiclename<>y.vehiclename you would use the UID.

```
    Declare @CustomerData Table (CustomerNum int,
                                 VehicleName Char(20),
             Vehiclepurchaseyear char(4),
            Vehicleprice char(10))
    INSERT INTO @CustomerData(CustomerNum,VehicleName,Vehiclepurchaseyear,Vehicleprice)
    VALUES (1000,'Toyoto Camry','2012',' 14500'),
           (1000,'Nissan Ultima','2014','12000'),
           (1500,'Honda Accord','2012','15000'),
           (1500,'Honda Civic','2012','13000'),
           (1800,'Toyoto RAV4','2012','16500')

    SELECT X.customerNum as CustomerNum
      ,X.VehicleName as Vehiclename1   
      ,X.Vehiclepurchaseyear as  vehiclepurchaseyear1 
      ,X.Vehicleprice        as  vehicleprice1 
      ,Y.VehicleName as Vehiclename2   
      ,Y.Vehiclepurchaseyear as  vehiclepurchaseyear2
      ,Y.Vehicleprice        as  vehicleprice2
FROM 
(SELECT CustomerNum,VehicleName,Vehiclepurchaseyear,Vehicleprice
from @Customerdata ) X
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT CustomerNum,VehicleName,Vehiclepurchaseyear,Vehicleprice
from @CustomerData ) Y
on X.CustomerNum = Y.customernum
and X.VehicleName<>Y.VehicleName
```